# Jquery syncronous ajax call not updating UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface

I have a syncronous ajax call which gets executed in a loop. I am trying to update the UI before any ajax call is executed and on the done call back method of each all.The UI is only updated after all ajax calls are made. Here is my code.

```
$("#warning").text("Do not close this screen!");
    setTimeout(function () { console.log("delay before ajax call") }, 4000);

    var strVale = document.getElementById('CompanyList').value;
    arr = strVale.split(',');
    LoadingPanel.Show();
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {

        var d = new Date();
        var date = [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth() + 1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
        var time = [pad(d.getHours()), pad(d.getMinutes())].join(':');

        $("#" + arr[i]).text("Started at " + date + " " + time);
        $("#" + arr[i]).css('background-color', 'orange');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            contentType: "'application/json; charset=utf-8'",
            url: "/url?companyID=" + parseInt(arr[i]),                
        }).done(function (response) {
            // console.log(response);
            if (response.Success) {
                $("#" + response.CompanyID).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
            }
            else {
                $("#" + response.CompanyID).css('background-color', 'lightpink');
            }

            $("#" + response.CompanyID).text(response.StatusMessage);
        });


    }

    LoadingPanel.Hide();
```

Comment: What's your question? Did you check Firebug->Console for any errors or something? Some more details would be great.

Comment: And what is the need for performing the ajax calls synchronously?

Comment: That's the usual behaviour: rendering of the newly added elements stops as soon as the next (synchronous) ajax gets executed. In order to have the ajax in "the background" while UI is updating, make async calls.

Comment: @satafaka There is no error, the updating should happen in between calls, done method of each ajax. It happens after all calls are done.

Comment: Did you try with async: true ?

Comment: @DanielB spec says to do it consequtively

Comment: What spec? Update your question and describe what you want to achieve and why you are using synchronous requests instead of asynchronous. There is for sure a more clean and effective way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with your async: false
if you make it true, it will work